Embedding promotion text into article at diffrent points
We have promotional text (text A) that we want to embed into in article (text B) at specific different points, e.g. at 25% or 50% etc. The problem is, after adding it, text A is not displaying in text B.
The code was done by a developer who we can't reach. It's a WordPress snippet code in PHP.
Not sure if this explanation makes sense, feel free to ask clarifying questions.
Here is the coding that we have:
add_filter( 'the_content', 'move_custom_content_in_the_main_loop', 1 );
function move_custom_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
// Only proceed if it's a single post and the main query.
// Note: Removed in_the_loop() check as it may not behave as expected with Elementor.
if ( is_singular() && is_main_query()  && get_the_ID() == 21197 ) {
// Retrieve ACF field values.
$acf_value = get_field( 'kies_promosie' );
$acf_value_2 = get_field( 'kies_promosie_2' );
$acf_value_3 = get_field( 'kies_promosie_3' );
    // Split the content into paragraphs.
    $paragraphs = preg_split( '/<\/p>/', $content );
    $total_paragraphs = count($paragraphs);
    $insertions = 0;

    // Ensure there are paragraphs to work with.
    if ($total_paragraphs > 0) {
        // Insertions for each ACF field if they have values.
        if ( $acf_value ) {
            $first_position = max(round(0.25 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $first_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="8471"]' ) . '</p>' );
            $insertions++;
        }

        if ( $acf_value_2 ) {
            $second_position = max(round(0.5 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $second_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="16315"]' ) . '</p>' );
            $insertions++;
        }

        if ( $acf_value_3 ) {
            $third_position = max(round(0.75 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $third_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="16316"]' ) . '</p>' );
        }

        // Reconstruct the content.
        $content = implode( '</p>', $paragraphs );
    }
}

return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'move_custom_content_in_the_main_loop', 1 );
function move_custom_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
// Only proceed if it's a single post and the main query.
// Note: Removed in_the_loop() check as it may not behave as expected with Elementor.
if ( is_singular() && is_main_query()  && get_the_ID() == 21197 ) {
// Retrieve ACF field values.
$acf_value = get_field( 'kies_promosie' );
$acf_value_2 = get_field( 'kies_promosie_2' );
$acf_value_3 = get_field( 'kies_promosie_3' );
    // Split the content into paragraphs.
    $paragraphs = preg_split( '/<\/p>/', $content );
    $total_paragraphs = count($paragraphs);
    $insertions = 0;

    // Ensure there are paragraphs to work with.
    if ($total_paragraphs > 0) {
        // Insertions for each ACF field if they have values.
        if ( $acf_value ) {
            $first_position = max(round(0.25 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $first_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="8471"]' ) . '</p>' );
            $insertions++;
        }

        if ( $acf_value_2 ) {
            $second_position = max(round(0.5 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $second_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="16315"]' ) . '</p>' );
            $insertions++;
        }

        if ( $acf_value_3 ) {
            $third_position = max(round(0.75 * $total_paragraphs) - 1 + $insertions, 0);
            array_splice( $paragraphs, $third_position, 0, '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="16316"]' ) . '</p>' );
        }

        // Reconstruct the content.
        $content = implode( '</p>', $paragraphs );
    }
}

return $content;

}
